# How to ask location permission flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, location, prompt, geolocator

I want only the prompt that asks permission for location to be displayed on the screen when the app is opened(only for demo purpose).
I don't want to use any packages for geocoding.

**please give the flutter code for this**

Answer (score 1):

If its only for a demo use an alert dialog

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: const <Widget>[
              Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
              Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Approve'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

More about alert dialog
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html

Please notethat thispop up will not enable location permission. Its only for a demo